# Hardware ID missing on Galaxy S3 after Windows update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb-connection-mode

A few days ago I accepted Windows Update's Samsung drivers for Galaxy S3 running rooted Jelly Bean. It worked fine as USB MTP device until then.

Now, every time I connect the USB cable I get the error "Hardware ID missing. Contact manufacturer..." and I can't see my device's file system.

Switching to PTP or enabling Debug doesn't work.

How to fix it?

Comment: Yes, it worked, I erased the crappy samsung driver, and the kies software, and everything is working good in my old windows vista 64. Just copy and drop. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your device is connected. Open `Device Manager`. In `USB Devices`, find a `SAMSUNG` composite device (can't capture a screenshot because it goes away).

Right click, choose `Uninstall` and make sure to check "get rid of that *sheet* of driver software"... Well... I mean "delete driver software too".

Disconnect and reconnect USB, or clik Detect Devices button

[image: Magic button]

Windows detects the phone and installs the plain old MTP driver.

Optional step: report to Samsung

Optional step 2: upvote :)

Comment: lol @ *Optional Step 2*!  +1 from me :)

Comment: Community wikis can't be upvoted :)

Comment: Nah... If they can't be upvoted, my +1 will be invisible *LOL*